# same script, same library, different output; why?

Tags: python, cross-platform, python-imaging-library

I'm using Pillow in order to resize and crop an image. Same libraries are installed both on a Win-XP 32Bit machine and a Linux Debian 8.0 machine.

Running following script outputs such different result that one can be recognized by [Ocrad](http://www.gnu.org/software/ocrad/) and other can not.

Script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PIL import Image


img = Image.open("a.BMP")
c = 4
img = img.resize((1280*c, 1024*c), Image.ANTIALIAS)

#box = (left, upper, right, lower)
box = (2481, 548, 2666, 1344)
img2 = img.crop(box)
img2.save("test.pbm")
```

OCR on result:

```
$ ocrad test-win32.pbm --filter=numbers
27.29

$ ocrad test-linux.pbm --filter=numbers
__._9
```

These are the images:

https://aktos-elektronik.com/static/public/2ruWQJ5FeEGU/test-win32.pbm

https://aktos-elektronik.com/static/public/2ruWQJ5FeEGU/test-linux.pbm

What could cause this result?

## Edit:

Source image (`a.BMP`) would be helpful for inspection but since I can't provide the image, I reissued the problem:

- input image: [test2-orig.png](https://aktos-elektronik.com/static/public/2ruWQJ5FeEGU/test2-orig.png)
- output image on windows: [test2-win32.png](https://aktos-elektronik.com/static/public/2ruWQJ5FeEGU/test2-win32.png)
- output image on linux: [test2-linux.png](https://aktos-elektronik.com/static/public/2ruWQJ5FeEGU/test2-linux.png)

code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PIL import Image


img = Image.open("test2-orig.png")
c = 2
img = img.resize((img.size[0]*c, img.size[1]*c), Image.ANTIALIAS)

#box = (left, upper, right, lower)
box = (170*c, 167*c, 216*c, 189*c)
img2 = img.crop(box)
img2.save("test2.png")
```

OCR output:

```
$ pngtopnm test2-win32.png | ocrad -s 4 -T 0.3
27.29

$ pngtopnm test2-linux.png | ocrad -s 4 -T 0.3
27.2_
```

Comment: platform differences? They look visually very similar, but their md5's are different.

Comment: so, where is the "code portability" of Python? (or maybe Pillow, in this case)

Comment: Can you upload `a.pbm` so people can experiment with it?

Comment: see "Edit" part of question.